# Can't access files in Public folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have put three files in my public folder. One is a HTML file. I can access this through https://domain.com/file.html

When I try to access either of the other two files through the same method (a .ipa and a .plist) it tells me the file is not found - but I definitely uploaded them. I'm sure this is a beginners question but I'm struggling to find an answer. A link in the HTML needs to be able to access one of them and a link in that file (the plist) will direct to the ipa.

I have tried creating routes to the files but that didn't work.

Comment: did you check `serve_static_assets`?

Comment: It was true. I moved the two files to the public/assets folder and changed it to false and it still isn't working. Error is: ```ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/file.ipa```

Comment: Do you have an `.htaccess` file getting in the way?

Comment: I don't think so. there is none in the project. For the server I'm using Heroku if that makes any difference.

Comment: I checked heroku through bash and the files are showing up when I run ls public/assets

Answer (score 1):

serve_static_assets worked for me. I was running my Rails application in a Docker Container with Puma. No Apache, nor Nginx to serve static assets.

Answer (score 1):

If you have default row in config (actual for Rails 6):

```
# config/environments/production.rb
config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
```

You can append fix it to `config.public_file_server.enabled = true`.

Or append this variable to start command or docker config file:

`RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=1`